# Error in using EXCEPT with INTERSECT in SQL

Tags: sql, database

Suppose I have three tables Table A,Table B and Table C.

Table A contains the col t1 with entries 1,2,2,3,4,4.
Table B has col t2 with entries 1,3,4,4.
Table C has col t3 with entries 1,2,4,4.

The query given was

```
SELECT * FROM  A EXCEPT (SELECT * FROM  B INTERSECT SELECT * FROM C ).
```

I saw this question in a test paper. It was mentioned that the expected answer was 2 but the answer obtained from this query was 1,2,4. I am not able to understand the principle behind this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, as I see it, both the expected answer and the answer you obtained are wrong. It may be the RDBMS that you are using, but analyzing your query the results should be `2,3`. First you should do the `INTERSECT` between tables `B` and `C`, the values that intersect are `1` and `4`. Taking that result, you should take all the values from table `A` except `1` and `4`, that leaves us with `2` and `3` (since `EXCEPT` and `INTERSECT` return only distinct values). [Here is a sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/49431/1) with this for you to try.

Comment: Can we use intersect along with except??

Comment: @geeko_zac - I'm not really sure what you mean, you are using both intersect and except on your example

Answer (score 1):

Because of the bracket, the INTERSECT between `B` and `C` is done first, resulting in (1,4).  You can even verify this just be taking the latter part and running in isolation:

```
SELECT * FROM  B INTERSECT SELECT * FROM C
```

The next step is to select everything in `A` EXCEPT those that exist in the previous result of (1,4), which leaves (2,3).

The answer should be 2 and 3, not 1,2 and 4.

BTW, it should be mentioned that even if you had no parenthesis in the query at all, the result should still be the same because the INTERSECT operator has a higher precedence than the EXCEPT/UNION operators.  This is the [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) documentation but it's consistent with the standard that applies to any DBMS that implements these operators.